# Vue.js doesn't work when mixed with underscore.js?

Tags: underscore.js, template-engine, vue.js

I have the following underscore.js template which has vue.js inside it. However I've noticed vue.js doesn't seem to work when it's mixed inside a underscore.js template.

```
    <div id='my-container'></div>


    <script id="my-template" type="text/template">

         <th class="initial " v-bind:class="{'active': isActive}"  v-on:click="dayFilter" >
             <span class="wkday"><%= day %></span>
         </th>

    </script>


     var clndr = $('#my-container').clndr({
          template: $('#my-template').html()
     });


    new Vue({
      el: '#my-container',

      data: {
        isActive: false
      },

      methods: {
        dayFilter: function () {
            this.isActive = ! this.isActive;
        }
      }

    })
```

Comment: Is clndr rendering the HTML asynchronously? If so, the Vue VM will not see anything when it is instantiated. Make sure that the Vue VM is attached after the rendering is complete.

Comment: It's not being rendered asynchronously. How would you attached Vue VM after the rendering is complete?

Comment: How about this – can you send to the console the html contents of #my-container right before the new Vue call?